# Spring data JPA no converter found capable of converting to view type

Tags: java, spring, database, kotlin, spring-data-jpa

I have encountered a problem with union mapping to view in Spring Data JPA.

Error:

```
Error:

org.springframework.core.convert.ConverterNotFoundException: No converter found capable of converting from type [org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.query.AbstractJpaQuery$TupleConverter$TupleBackedMap] to type path.PlayerAccountView
```

My current implementation:

```
@Query(
value = """
SELECT user_uid, operator_uid FROM player_account_table_one WHERE job_id = :sessionId
UNION
SELECT user_uid, operator_uid FROM player_account_table_two WHERE job_id = :sessionId
UNION
SELECT user_uid, operator_uid FROM player_account_table_three WHERE job_id = :sessionId
UNION
SELECT user_uid, operator_uid FROM player_account_table_four WHERE job_id = :sessionId
UNION
SELECT user_uid, operator_uid FROM player_account_table_five WHERE job_id = :sessionId
UNION
SELECT user_uid, operator_uid FROM player_account_table_six WHERE job_id = :sessionId
""",
    nativeQuery = true,
)
fun findUsersViewResult(@Param("sessionId") sessionId: Long): List<PlayerAccountView>
```

View class:

```
data class PlayerAccountView(
val playerUid: String = Nil.String,
val operatorUid: String = Nil.String,
```

)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have 2 options to avoid this exception:

1-Define and reference a @NamedNativeQuery with an @SqlResultSetMapping.
2-Use a fragment interface to provide your own implementation of a repository method.